# Unicode overwriting keyboard shortcuts

Tags: input, language

I needed to input some Russian characters so used `setxkbmap ru`. To switch back I used `setxkbmap gb` (from awkwardly compounding previous commands from history - be warned...)

But now when I use shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in every program an underlined 'u' is output rather than the expected action.

I see mention of ibus in other answers or using GUI language settings but I am running Archlabs linux and I cannot find any language options.